# how to subset data using two other dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with ID's (100) and each ID has different number of rows and all ID's have same number of columns.

the sample dataframe looks like as follows

```
a <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
              A = c(12,12.5,15,16,18,20,25,26,29,35, 12,12.5,15,16,18,20,25,26,29,35),
              B = c(20,19,18,17,16,20,25,28,30,35, 20,19,18,17,16,20,25,28,30,35),
              C = c(2,1,5,9,10,11,13,18,25,27,2,1,5,9,10,11,13,18,25,27))
```

in each ID I want to subset the data between two specified values, these two values are in two other dataframes respectively.

the first value is the first row of each ID and the sample dataframe is as follows

```
 b <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), 
              A = c(12.0,12.0),
              B = c(20,20),
              C = c(2,2))
```

the second value is the specified row based on some value in a vector and the sample dataframe is as follows

```
c <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), 
               A = c(25.0,20.0),
               B = c(25,20),
               C = c(13,11))
```

if we can observe, the rows corresponding to each ID, the values are same as in the main dataframe 'a'

the expected dataframe is as follows

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
              A = c(12,12.5,15,16,18,20,25, 12,12.5,15,16,18,20),
              B = c(20,19,18,17,16,20,25, 20,19,18,17,16,20),
              C = c(2,1,5,9,10,11,13,2,1,5,9,10,11))
```

to get the expected output, I have tried the following code.....but failed

```
for (i in 1:nrow(b)){
Azimuth[i] = (a[which(a$A == b$A[i]):which(a$A == c$A[i])])
}
```

here, I am trying to use two dataframes 'b' and 'c' to subset the data from 'a'. but is it possible to get the same output without using dataframe 'b'?! because in dataframe 'b', each row is the first row in each ID from dataframe 'a'

Comment: I did not understand how you want to subset your data. But you can use the `subset()` function. This is probably easier than what you did :)

Comment: i am pretty sure you can not use `which()` inside of [ ]. that would also defeat the point even if it was possible

Comment: For each `ID` would all `A`, `B` and `C` value start and end at the same row always? If no, how would the output look when for ID = 1, `A` starts at row 1 and ends at row 5 whereas `B` starts at row 2 and ends at row 10? If yes, why do you need 3 columns (A, B and C) then? Only 1 of them is enough.

Comment: so basically you want something like this, right? `for (i in a$A){
  if(between(i, min(b$A), max(c$A))){
    print(i)
  }
}
`

Comment: the rows in dataframe 'b', is the first row of every ID in dataframe 'a'  .......but the rows in dataframe 'c' can be any row of that ID in dataframe 'a'. the row values are same in all the three dataframes 'a', 'b', and 'c'. i am looking for the code that subsets the data above to each row in dataframe 'a' based on dataframe 'c' @RonakShah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  mutate(end = FALSE) %>% 
  rows_update(c %>% mutate(end = TRUE), by = c("ID", "A", "B", "C")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(1:which(end)) %>% 
  select(-end)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID     A     B     C
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  12      20     2
 2     1  12.5    19     1
 3     1  15      18     5
 4     1  16      17     9
 5     1  18      16    10
 6     1  20      20    11
 7     1  25      25    13
 8     2  12      20     2
 9     2  12.5    19     1
10     2  15      18     5
11     2  16      17     9
12     2  18      16    10
13     2  20      20    11
```

Explanation:

I guess you want to use a dataframe to subset another one because you want to subset `a` only if there exist certain combinations of `ID`, `A`, `B` and `C`, which you specify in your dataframe `c`?

If that is the case, your goal can be achieved by taking the following steps:

1. We create another logical variable in `a`. Call it `end` and default to `FALSE`.
2. We also create the same variable in `c` but set its default to `TRUE`.
3. We use `end` in `c` to update the `end` in `a` for each row marked by a combination of `ID`, `A`, `B` and `C`. In this way, the variable `end` will become `TRUE` only when there is a full match between `a` and `c` for the other four variables. If you cannot find a full match, then you will get this
   `Error: Attempting to update missing rows.`
4. We `group_by(ID)` and select from the first row until where `end`  is `TRUE` for each group defined by `ID`.
5. You drop that `end` variable since it has no use any more.

Comment: according to your solution, we can subset dataframe 'a' using dataframe 'c' from 1st row of a particular ID in a'th dataframe to the row of the c'th dataframe of that particular ID in a'th dataframe. then, how to do it reverse i.e. subsetting dataframe 'a' from the row of a particular ID in c'th dataframe in dataframe 'a' to last row of a particular ID in dataframe 'a'?

Comment: @Kumar change `slice(1:which(end))` to `slice(which(end):n())`

Comment: in your solution in 4th line from top, can we replace 'by = c("ID", "A", "B", "C")' with 'by= colnames(a)'....?!